# Controls are updated by INotifyPropertyChanged but not the list in the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I've implemented *INotifyPropertyChanged* and the update in my GUI works as supposed to. If the view model changes a value, the control in the window updates.

However, I also have a *DataGrid* control and the update in view model doesn't propagate to the GUI. If I change something in the the table and invoke store, the changed values are available for VM, including newly added rows.

I've looked at other classes, like *INotifyCollectionChanged* but got no wiser. Should I move over and use *ObservableCollection* or is there a more recommended approach?

Comment: I'd go ObservableCollection myself, but a minimal example showing your problem wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IObservable is the way to go to notify the View of changes. As you have mentioned you models are already implenting INotifyPropertyChanged, so your in a good spot to take advantage of it.